# Html list item keep active on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having an issue which i would like to solve. i have created a menu for an ecommerce site. The menu works fine. Unfortunately i cannot copy the whole code here cos it is too much but i made a short version and a picture to present the structure of the menu.
The main concept is when a button is clicked on the main nav a dropdown menu opens which has 2 columns. The left site has further buttons and the right side is where the div containers will be shown depending on the active list item on the left side. That is where the issue occours.
Because the container opens by hovering on the list item not by clicking it. When the mouse is over the li it gets highlighted but when the mouse is out the highlight color disappears.
I would like to keep the active li item highlighted until the mouse hovers on another li item.
Somehow i should get the row(item) which is hovered, change the css class for highlighted and keep until another row gets hovered. Then remove the css class and do the same with the new active list.
Hope i mad it clear. :-)
here are the html codes and the structure.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" id="button1"> </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">                 

            <div class="col-sm-3">
            <ul class="submenu-list">
                <li><a href="#" class="submenu-list-item" id="item1"> </a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="submenu-list-item " id="item2"> </a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="submenu-list-item " id="item3"> </a></li>
            </ul>
            </div> 

            <div class="col-sm-9" id="submenubox1">
                <h3>Subbox Title</h3>
                <div>Content</div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-9" id="submenubox2">
                <h3>Subbox Title</h3>
                <div>Content</div>
            </div>

        </div>
        </li>  
    </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

[image]
The code im trying is the following using the menu.aim javascript:

```
<script src="jquery.menu-aim.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>

        var $menu = $(".dropdown-menu");
        $menu.menuAim({
            activate: activateSubmenu,
            deactivate: deactivateSubmenu
        });

        function activateSubmenu(row) {
            var $row = $(row);
            // Keep the currently activated row's highlighted look
            $row.find("a").addClass("maintainHover");
        }

        function deactivateSubmenu(row) {
            //remove the row's highlighted look
            $row.find("a").removeClass("maintainHover");
        }
</script>
```

however this code is not working. Im am not sure if this would be the right way to solve this thought.
Also i have tried to use to css code:

```
ul.class li:hover{
background-color: red !important;
}
```

But this is not working either.

Here is a similar example what iam trying to achieve.
https://rawgit.com/kamens/jQuery-menu-aim/master/example/example.html

Any help would be appropriated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery to add an `active` class to the hovered item -

```
$('.submenu-list-item:not(.active)').on('mouseover', function() {
  $(this).parent().find('.submenu-list-item.active').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

This will add `active` class only when hovered over items of the same parent i.e. same submenu

Comment: Hi. Thanks. Half way there. :-) For some reason when i hover on the li it gets highlighted and stays highlighted. But the problem is that when i hover on another li that gets highlighted but the last one stays as well. For some reason the first highlight does not disappear although the parent find removeclass should do that.

Comment: @bontoo had it worked fully? or problem is still there? Can you see in the code inspector that the class is removed or not and if any JS error occurs in the console?

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat I can understand your question. I have tried this plugin. It may satisfy your need.
[Bootstrap Submenu](https://vsn4ik.github.io/bootstrap-submenu/)

Answer (score 0):

Thanx for all replies.
With the help of Rohit answer I made it work.

However I had to change a line.

```
$(this).parent().find('.submenu-list-item.active').removeClass('active');
```

this line was not working for me unfortunatelly.
It did not remove the highlighted item once another got hovered on. Instead of this I removed the class from all items(a) in the ul.

```
$('.submenu-list-item:not(.active)').on('mouseover', function() {
$(".submenu-list a").removeClass();
$(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Anyway thanks for the bootstrap answer as well. I will learn some new stuffs from there.